# Flyway dependencies can't be resolved after changing branches

Tags: spring, git, spring-boot, gradle, flyway

I am working on a separate branch on a project, in which I had to implement Flyway. It worked out well, after I staged, committed and pushed everything to my branch.

I have done the checkout to the master branch, pulled, moved back to my own branch. My code is the same, there is no data loss, but somehow, my Flyway dependencies can't be resolved in build.gradle, thus the import

`import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;`

in the application can't be recognized.

```
flyway {
 schemas = ['ApplicationUser', 'Kingdom']
 placeholders = [
         'keyABC'          : 'valueXYZ',
         'otherplaceholder': 'value123'
]


url = (System.getenv("database"))
user = (System.getenv("db_username"))
password = (System.getenv("db_password"))
```

The error message I get here: "Cannot resolve 'flyway'".

My other dependencies regarding Flyway in build.gradle:

```
plugins {
 id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "5.2.4"
}

dependencies {
 implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
 compile "org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.2.4"
 flywayMigration "com.xy.z"
```

Could you help me figure out what the problem can be, and help me sort out this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just an IDE thing? Do you actually get an error when you compile your project in CLI (`gradle build`)?

Comment: Unfortunately I get an arror.
The relevant part of the stack trace might be:
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: 
Could not find method flywayMigration() for arguments [com.xy.z] object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Answer (score 0):

With Gradle, you have to define custom configurations like `flywayMigration` before using it in the dependencies.

Like this :

```
configurations {
  flywayMigration
}

dependencies {
  ...
  flywayMigration "com.xy.z"
}
```

It seems like the configurations part is missing from your gradle build config.

See [Gradle doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_dependency_configurations.html#defining_custom_configurations) and [Flyway doc](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/gradle/#extending-the-default-classpath)